# Dijsktra's algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, function, dijkstra, shortest-path

I'm trying to implement Dijsktra's algorithm in C#.

My code has an error in the function to find the vertex with minimum distance value, from the set of vertices not yet included in shortest path tree.

**The error says Use of unassigned local variable 'min_index'.** and it occurs on return min_index;

Can you tell me what i did wrong please ?

Here is the code of the function =

```
    // Utility function to find the vertex with minimum distance value, from 
    // the set of vertices not yet included in shortest path tree
    int minDistance (int[] dist, bool[] sptSet)
    {
        // Initialize min value
        int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        {
            if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            {
                min = dist[v];
                min_index = v;
            }
        }

        return min_index;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but it's clearer to say `!sptSet[v]` instead of `sptSet[v] == false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method **may** return value of the `min_index` that has never been set.
You should initialize it before:

```
int min = INT_MAX;
int min_index = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in case your if condition fails every time, you're trying to return a value that is unassigned.